# How cgroup can limit the command dd to write to the disk

Tags: linux, cgroups

Right now I am working on cgroup devices subsystem, I want to allow only some process to access my USB drive. for example: If dd is not in allowed process, the dd command shouldnt able to write to the device.

I have tried putting "a 8:* mr" into device allow list, but how to set the trusted process here. Trusted process means, a process for  which I gave permission to access the device.